# hi how can i select empty space in the window using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi i want a part of the code to get executed when i click on an empty space in the window where there is nothing no `p` no `div` just nothing but i still see the console code even if i click on a `p` in the window,so if there is another way to tackle that problem i will appreciate your help.

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(div, p)", function(){
    console.log("you clicked nothing just empty zone in the window" ); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the click is only in the `body` element.  This works even if you have `span`, `a`, `button`, etc. elements.

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: think's it work first the body was to small but when i set min-height and make the body bigger the code get exectud i think i learned something new from you think's.

Comment: yeah got the same thing, if the body doesn't cover the entire page you'll click on the `<html>`, and that doesn't work 'cause the click-handler is attached to the `<body>`... If you set `body {width:100%; height:100%;`} in CSS, I think it should always work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if (!$('div , p').is(e.target)){
       console.log("you clicked nothing just empty zone in the window" ); 
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hupf7ngw/)

Comment: i try this one but it didn't work and the part of the code don't get executed at all even if i click empty space.think's any way.